# Bash concatenate a field if key-field match

Tags: bash, csv, string-concatenation

i got this kind of text file : id;firstname;client;invoice;comments (this is an exemple)

```
001;peter;35621;C132;foo
002;jane;12345;A546;
003;robert;78945;Z456;some comments
001;peter;35621;Y456;blabla
004;terry;89740;T897;
003;robert;78945;L546;bar
```

what i want to do is to concatenate the invoice field in another field at the end of each line depending on the client. i can only use bash or unix cli tools (awk,sed,cut,etc...)
which in this case should produce :

```
001;peter;35621;C132;foo;;C132/Y456
002;jane;12345;A546;;A546
003;robert;78945;Z456;some comments;Z456/L546
001;peter;35621;Y456;blabla;C132/Y456
004;terry;89740;T897;;T897
003;robert;78945;L546;bar;Z456/L546
```

what i have done so far : (but i'm not really happy with the result as it seems really ugly)

```
#!/bin/bash

file="myfile.txt"

while IFS=\; read id firstname client invoice comments
do
    catInvoice=""
    while IFS=\; read xid xfirstname xclient xinvoice xcomments
    do
        if [ $client == $xclient ]
            then
                catInvoice="$catInvoice/$xinvoice"
        fi
    done < $file
    catInvoice=`echo $catInvoice | sed 's/^\///'`
    echo "$id;$firstname;$client;$invoice;$comments;$catInvoice"
done < $file
```

any suggestions ?
thanks.

Comment: How did robert get L546 invoice? It's missing in your sample file

Comment: yep sorry my bad. Corrected now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two passes to the file, but does the trick:

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}
NR==FNR{a[$2]=(a[$2])?a[$2]"/"$4:$4;next}
{print $0,a[$2]}' textfile textfile
```

#### Output: Assuming there is a typo in your sample file (i.e Robert is missing L546 invoice which appears in your output.

```
$ cat textfile 
001;peter;35621;C132;foo
002;jane;12345;A546;
003;robert;78945;Z456;some comments
001;peter;35621;Y456;blabla
004;terry;89740;T897;
003;robert;78945;L546;bar

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}NR==FNR{a[$2]=(a[$2])?a[$2]"/"$4:$4;next}{print $0,a[$2]}' textfile textfile
001;peter;35621;C132;foo;C132/Y456
002;jane;12345;A546;;A546
003;robert;78945;Z456;some comments;Z456/L546
001;peter;35621;Y456;blabla;C132/Y456
004;terry;89740;T897;;T897
003;robert;78945;L546;bar;Z456/L546
```

Comment: Wow, amazing... just what i'm looking for. I will keep this carefully under my pillow ;)... thanks JS.